# JS internal function not being executed on IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with a javascript function on my webpages, it works for FF but not for IE8.
Here is how it is called :

```
<div class="inscription-content-titre pacifico p48 textfontcolor">
                <input id="supporter" type="radio" name="group" value="Supporter" class="mlm" onclick="javascript:handleForm('supporter')" required/>
                <label class="labelmargintop" for="supporter">{{ 'inscription.supporter.titre'|trans({}, 'messages') }}</label>
</div>
```

and the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleForm(group)
    {
        if(group == 'fan'){
            document.getElementById('supporter_form').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('supporter_list_header').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('fan_list_header').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('fan_list').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('footer_checkbox').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('footer_button').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('supporter_list').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('supporter_form').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('supporter_list_header').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('fan_list_header').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('fan_list').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('footer_checkbox').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('footer_button').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('supporter_list').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

For reason i don't know ie comes out with a strange error that says the value of the property handleForm is null or undefined, not a function object.

Do anyone as an idea why IE would not execute my code ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using Angular > 1.3, in which case, [IE8 is not supported](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

There could be a number of things, some things to try include changing out the variable replacement (or simplifying it) or getting rid of the `required` attribute as [IE8 does not support that either](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

You also do not need the `javascript:` bit, `onclick="handleForm( 'supporter' )` is all that is required, although it should be ringing alarm bells why you aren’t handling that function as part of your Angular stuff. Seems odd to mix global functionality with angular-powered functionality, although this does not relate to your question, more of an observation.

Comment: I don't use angular at all so i don't think the probleme comes from that i have tried to get rid of the javascript: and it seems to work thanks :)

Comment: `{{ 'inscription.supporter.titre'|trans({}, 'messages') }}`, sorry, assumed this was framework code, guess it must be template.